# Numpy: how to return a view on a matrix A based on submatrix B

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

Given a matrix A with dimensions axa, and B with dimensions bxb, and axa modulo bxb == 0. B is a submatrix(s) of A starting at (0,0) and tiled until the dimensions of axa is met.

```
A = array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
           [ 4,  5,  6,  7],
           [ 8,  9, 10, 11],
           [12, 13, 14, 15]])
```

An example of a submatrix might be:

```
B = array([[10, 11],
           [14, 15]])
```

Where the number 15 is in position (1, 1) with respect to B's coordinates.

How could I return a view on the array A, for a particular position in B? For example for position (1,1) in B, I want to get all such values from A:

```
C = array([[5, 7],
           [13, 15]])
```

The reason I want a view, is that I wish to update multiple positions in A:

```
C = array([[5, 7],[13, 15]]) = 20
```

results in

```
A = array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
           [ 4,  20,  6, 20],
           [ 8,  9, 10, 11],
           [12, 20, 14, 20]])
```

Comment: When used as ``A[...]=....` the indexing can be advanced (a copy creator when used in the `getitem` sense).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can obtain this as follows:

```
>>> A = np.array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
           [ 4,  5,  6,  7],
           [ 8,  9, 10, 11],
           [12, 13, 14, 15]])
>>> A[np.ix_([1,3],[1,3])] = 20
>>> A
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
       [ 4, 20,  6, 20],
       [ 8,  9, 10, 11],
       [12, 20, 14, 20]])
```

For more info about `np.ix_` could review the [NumPy documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ix_.html)

Comment: It might be worth writing `[1,3]` as `[1,1+len(B)]` for a bit more clarity.

Comment: Excellent thanks Pedro, I didn't realise how much Numpy gives to us.